# how to convert markdown to html?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I want to convert a string as (markdown) to html.
There are other libraries like [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown)
But libraries like this are meant to render the markdown as

```
<ReactMarkdown  children={input} />
```

The above is a react element.
I dont want to render it . I just want a function which converts the markdown to pure html.
Something like

```
let markdown="#hello";
let html=convertMarkdownToHtml(markdown);
```

Comment: https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js/ works well for me or https://github.com/markedjs/marked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've used the [react-showdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-showdown) package for one of my projects.

There is actually one that's meant for pure JavaScript which can store the HTML in a variable as text. It's [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown).

From the docs, the simple example provided is this:

```js
var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
    text      = '# hello, markdown!',
    html      = converter.makeHtml(text);
```

The output is equal to

```html
<h1 id="hellomarkdown">hello, markdown!</h1>
```

I've included a runnable example for you, below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/2.1.0/showdown.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
            text      = `
# hello, markdown!

- list1
- list2
- list3
            `,
            html      = converter.makeHtml(text);

        console.log(html);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```